Can S.M.A.R.T. values be reset?
Manufacturers can reset the S.M.A.R.T. values of refurbished/recertified drives.
Can anyone else except the manufacturer reset S.M.A.R.T. values,
e.g. reset spin-up count to zero or reset drive usage hours to zero ?
Could, for example, a HDD retailer reset the S.M.A.R.T. values in order to (re)sell used HDDs as new? (Similarly to the fraud of tempering with the mileage counter of cars.) Do users need to worry about this?

never buy a storage device from someone you don't trust, especially if the offer is too good to be true. other parts may be less risky (they work or they don't) but shady storage will bite you twice when it fails, and you lose your data too.

@Frank: I hear you and you are certainly right. Could you spell out the specific risks you think of when buying a trusted brand HDD from an unknown retailer compared to a trusted retailer?
